# Remotely update devices with raspberrypi

Tags: iot, remote-access, raspberry-pi4

I want to know if it is possible to update old devices with help of raspberrypi remotely. The only way to update my old devices is by plugging in usb stick containg the source code and autoexec.sh file. Once I plug in the usb drive the device automatically updates and reboots. I am curious to know if I can connect my device via usb to raspberry pi, emulate a usb drive and provide those file for update?.

Comment: What you propose *might* be possible with the Pi Zero (and possibly [the Pi 4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/100583)). [This](https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive) might get you started (there are related questions on [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) e.g. [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1088), [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/111878) and [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/67590)).